# OpenCV Matrix of different size

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matrix

I am having some problem with `Mat` in OpenCV. I was using SIFT for image classification with SVM. Now I realized that the true-positive rate was low, so I decided to add ORB feature detectors on top of SIFT. My problem is that, for example for one image:

SIFT descriptors: `Mat` size [128 x 250]

ORB descriptors: `Mat` size [32 x 400]

Now as for training matrix all the features have to be in the training matrix and than trained. Now, as you see that the 2 matrix of SIFT and ORB are of different size. How can I combine them into one matrix?.

***Do I have to append (add) the second matrix to the end of the first one because currently I am assigning it to separate columns.***

Please give me some hints on this please.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to extracting features based on your solution. The first part is to detect keypoints, and the second part is to describe them. At the moment, you are doing both stages with both SIFT and ORB, and coming up with matrices of different sizes. Instead, use the following framework:

```
// Construct detectors
cv::FeatureDetector siftDetector, orbDetector;
siftDetector.create("SIFT");
orbDetector.create("ORB");

// Detect keypoints
std::vector<cv::Keypoint> siftPoints, orbPoints;
siftDetector.detect(img, siftPoints);
orbDetector.detect(img, orbPoints);

// Concantenate the vectors
siftPoints.insert(siftPoints.end(), orbPoints.begin(), orbPoints.end());

// Construct descriptor (SIFT used as example)
cv::FeatureDescriptor siftDescriptor;
siftDescriptor.create("SIFT");

// Compute descriptors
cv::Mat descriptors;
siftDescriptor.compute(img, siftPoints, descriptors);
```

You now have SIFT descriptions for all detected keypoints.

PS: I haven't compiled this code, so double check for typos and syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explaination. Sorry i was sick so i didnt do anywork but i have a question. 1) Once we concatenate the vectors like you did ORB into Sift vector, than computing the descriptors do we need also to compute descriptors for ORB. I think yes but I am confused.

Comment: 2) I think the important vector is the descriptor vector which is used in the training system and if the answer to my question 1 is Yes than we need to concantenate the SIFT and ORB descriptors together like in the same way you have done for the keypoints. Sorry i might sound confused since i am new to this but your help has gave me insight on roughly how to go about doing it except just these 2 confusion. Thank you so much for you time!!

Comment: No you won't need to compute ORB descriptors at all. Just use ORB to detect keypoints, so that the overall number of keypoints increases, and then extract SIFT descriptors for all the keypoints. The concatenation of vectors happens only once for the keypoints vector.

Comment: ok i get that loud and clear. The important thing is the keypoints right which i was taking it wrongly. Thank you alot...cheers